# Chrome Extension Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to send a httpget request in chrome but I get this error 
**Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key**

here's my button code

```
contentInput.onclick = function(){
    var assetid = $('.thumbnail-span').attr("data-3d-url")
    var baseurl = 'http://www.roblox.com'
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", chrome.extension.getURL(baseurl + assetid), true);
    var result = xhr.responseText;
    xhr.send();
    console.log(result)
        chrome.extension.sendRequest({
            action: "EditContent",
            type: assetType,
            name: assetName, 
            content: contentData
        })
```

and my manifest file

```
{

        "name": "ROBLOX Object Downloader .obj",
        "short_name": "OBJDownloader",
        "description": "Allows you to quickly download assets from the browser as a .obj ",
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "icons": {"128":"icon.png"},
        "permissions": [
            "http://*.roblox.com/*",
            "http://*.rbxcdn.com/*",
            "downloads",
            "downloads.open"
        ],
        "background": {"scripts":["background.js"]},
           "content_scripts": [
                    {
                            "matches": ["http://*.roblox.com/*-item?id=*"],
                            "js": ["item.js","jquery.js"]
                    },
                    {
                            "matches": ["http://*.roblox.com/*ser.aspx*"],
                            "js": ["user.js","jquery.js"]
                    },
                    {
                            "matches": ["http://*.roblox.com/*atalog/*"],
                            "js": ["cataloginsert.js","jquery.js"]
                    }
            ],
        "manifest_version": 2
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`chrome.extension.getURL`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#method-getURL) function is used to get a file from your own computer located inside the extension's directory:

> `string chrome.extension.getURL(string path)`: Converts a relative path within an extension install directory to a fully-qualified URL.

This means your Ajax request is trying to access a URL like

```
chrome-extension://aaaaaabbbbbccccccdddddd/http://www.roblox.com/some-asset-id
```

In order to access files through `chrome-extension://`, you have to make them explicitly accessible to web pages through the `web_accessible_resource` manifest field.

However, you probably just want to get the web URL `http://www.roblox.com/some-asset-id`. In case, `getURL` is completely inappropriate. Simply do something like:

```
xhr.open("GET", baseurl + assetid, true);
```

Your code has an *additional* problem, which is that it doesn't wait for the asynchronous Ajax call to complete. You should wait for the `load` event and then read `responseText`:

```
contentInput.onclick = function(){
    ...
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", chrome.extension.getURL(baseurl + assetid), true);

    xhr.addEventListener("load", function() {
        var result = xhr.responseText;
        console.log(result);
        doSomethingElseWith(result);
        // all uses of `result` must be inside this function
    });

    xhr.send();

    ...
```

Comment: Alright so how come `var assetid = $('.thumbnail-span').attr("data-3d-url")
var baseurl = 'http://www.roblox.com'
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", baseurl + assetid, true);
var result = xhr.responseText;
xhr.send();
console.log(result)` doesn't show the result? IT just shows XHR finished loading: GET and another line that's blank

Comment: @user3851593 You're not waiting for the asynchronous call to complete; I've edited my answer.

Comment: @user3851593 Please don't try to paste multi-line code in comments. It looks _bad_.

Comment: One last question, The result is in JSON how would I get a specific value from that result? Json can be found here http://www.roblox.com/asset-thumbnail-3d/json?assetId=111795617 id like to get 'URL"

Comment: @user3851593 See [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to convert JSON response text into a JS object. If you have new questions, please feel free to open a new question -- questions on Stack Overflow should generally apply to one specific problem (so they can more easily help others with that one specific problem in the future).

Comment: Thanks! I just didn't want to spam I'll make a new post.